# `diag(R)` in QR after SVD with specific $\Sigma$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

```
[U,X] = qr(randn(10));
[V,X] = qr(randn(10));
S = diag(2 .^ (-1:-1:-10));
A = U*S*V

[Q,R] = qr(A)
```

Why diagonal of R contains numbers in decreasing order:

```
K>> diag(R)
```

ans =

> -0.1220
>      -0.0603
>       0.0341
>      -0.0802
>      -0.0543
>      -0.0146
>      -0.0048
>      -0.0051
>       0.0301
>       0.0024

If i change S to `diag(2 .^ (1:.1:1.9));` that's not the case any more. At least it is not so evident.

---

For now i can think only of that `U*S` gives us matrix with every next column contains twice less numbers than the previous one. So, when multiplying by `V` we kinda we weight every next row as twice less important. And because of this we lose some degree of independence in the resulted matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default QR decomposition, I don't think the decreasing diagonal is always true like SVD. There is a variation where it holds:

`[Q,R,E] = qr(A)` or `[Q,R,E] = qr(A,'matrix')` produces unitary `Q`, upper triangular `R` and a permutation matrix `E` so that `A*E = Q*R`. The column permutation `E` is chosen so that `abs(diag(R))` is decreasing.

Just compare the QR and SVD from `diag(1:3)`.